# How to bind and display characters in the function

Tags: r

Sorry but a very simple question.
I'm now implanting python code to R.
It's a very simple code related to handling characters, but doesn't run at all.
I need your help to correct my code.

Thank you in advance.

Python code

```
def hello(obj):  
  print("Hello" + obj +"!")  

hello("cat")
```

The output of the above code is

Hello cat!

My code in R

```
hello <- function(obj){  

  print("Hello ", obj, "!", quote=FALSE)  
}  

hello(cat)
```

1. Expected results
   Same as Python, that is,
   Hello cat!
2. Actual results
   Error in print.default("Hello", obj, "!", quote = FALSE) : invalid 'digits' argument

Comment: Wrap with `paste` `print(paste("Hello ", obj, "!"), quote=FALSE)` and then pass it as a string `hello("cat")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can wrap with `paste`

```
hello <- function(obj){  

  print(paste("Hello ", obj, "!", sep = ""), quote=FALSE) 
  #or use cat
  # cat("Hello ", obj, "!")  
}  

hello("cat")
#[1] Hello cat!
```

NOTE: Adding the `paste` from the comments

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. I confirmed your code runs with no problem. I'll check 'paste' function one more time.

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
hello <- function(obj){  

 noquote(paste0("Hello ", obj, "!")  )

 }  

hello("cat")

>[1] Hello cat!
```

If you want to "pretty print" it

```
hello <- function(obj){  

  cat(format(paste0("Hello ", obj, "!")  ))

  }  


> hello("cat")
Hello cat!
```

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply. I'll check carefully again how to use 'paste' function.